# How to use ILNumerics function csvread to load complex array from a csv file

Tags: csv, ilnumerics

I want to load a csv format data file with function csvread. The data is in complex format. For example, it looks like "36.151-202.64i,236.74+2.1788i,26.234+201.94i, ...."

When I call csvread with ILNumerics, I can only first column data. All other data are zeros.

Here is the simple 2 lines of code.
var inputDataFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Input.txt");            ILArray datComplex = csvread(inputDataFile);

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a popular request, and we are currently working on it. The upcoming version will support reading complex numbers and arbitrary formatted elements in CSV files. Stay tuned!